# JUnit test case is not running in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am using eclipse IDE in my java project, I have also configured "JUNIT" to my eclipse ide.
      When I am running a test case in eclipse using,
                  "Rightclick On Project->Run As",
      It is showing that "Run configurations".It is not showing "JUnitTestCase" .
      What is the problem?

Comment: Can you show your test, and tell us which version of JUnit you're using?

Comment: How you created the class using Junit Test Case ??

Answer (score 0):

Look at the project facets by right clicking on the project. Is Junit added?

Also as long as you have added junit to your project classpath you should get the option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten the @Test Annotation?